How can I programmatically generate SvelteKit routes?
I've been working on a simple CMS with SvelteKit. I want authenticated users to be able to create new pages or layouts within the application. I'm not sure if this would require the actual generation of +page.svelte or +layout.svelte files programmatically, or some way of dynamically loading routes from data (almost as if there was an equivalent of loading a list of components with an #each block, but for whole pages with their own url routes). Right now I'm storing data in JSON, along with the content for each page. It also seems a bit silly to create a bunch of empty directories simply for routing and layout inheritance purposes when all my data is already stored in JSON.
Would I do this using something like Node's File System API, or is there a SvelteKit specific way to generate directories, or load file routes dynamically from data?

After you have built your app, you can't dynamically add more +page.svelte or +layout.svelte files to it. So your users can only create data when they use your app. So somewhere on the server, you need to store data representing these new pages (e.g. an array with objects, where each object contains the data for respective page), and then you have one +page.svelte file to display one of those objects. To indicate which one, use a slug parameter.
A similar approach can also be used for layouts.

It can look something like this:
<script>
    
    const pageContent = `
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>How are you?</p>
    `
    
    // Either use this...
    const premadeLayoutOptions = {
        name: `plain`,
        headerName: `Header Name`,
        // ...
    }
    
    // Or use this...
    const customizableLayoutOptions = {
        headerContent: `<h1>Header Content</h1>`,
        menuContent: `<h1>Menu Content</h1>`,
        footerContent: `<h1>Footer Content</h1>`,
    }
    
    // Or use this...
    const customLayout = {
        code: `
            <div class="layout">
                
                <header>
                    Hello!
                </header>
                
                <main>
                    {{pageContent}}
                </main>
                
            </div>
        `
    }
    
    
</script>

{#if premadeLayoutOptions}
    
    {#if premadeLayoutOptions.name == `none`}
        <div class="layout none">
            <div class="content">
                {@html pageContent}
            </div>
        </div>
    {:else if premadeLayoutOptions.name == `plain`}
        <div class="layout plain">
            <header>
                {premadeLayoutOptions.headerName}
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                {@html pageContent}
            </div>
        </div>
    {/if}
    <!-- And then you have more premade layouts like this... -->
    
{/if}

{#if customizableLayoutOptions}
    <div class="layout customizable">
        
        <header>
            {@html customizableLayoutOptions.headerContent}
        </header>
        
        <header>
            {@html customizableLayoutOptions.menuContent}
        </header>
        
        <div class="content">
            {@html pageContent}
        </div>
        
        <header>
            {@html customizableLayoutOptions.footerContent}
        </header>
        
    </div>
    
{/if}

{#if customLayout}
    
    {@html customLayout.code.replace(`{{pageContent}}`, pageContent)}
    
{/if}


Hmmm, well that solves how to load data into things I already have templated out (blog posts for example), and just swapping out the data using the slug parameter. But how do I allow users to create their own layout elements?

I think we need more information about how you want it work. Do you have predefined layouts the user can choose from? Or can the user write arbitrary HTML code that should be used in the layout? Or does the layout always consist of (let's say) 4 sections (like a header, menu, page content and footer), and the user can only specify the content of these sections? Or how does writing a layout for the user work?

Ideally both. I would like the user to be able to control the layout. I want to be able to include premade layout/component options, but also allow user to create arbitrary layouts with custom html, or through combining premade generic elements in a visual editor. So for example, when they are editing a page, I want them to be able to choose to use a premade header, or be able to create their own, on a page by page basis.

@SamSabin Then it becomes a very, very broad question. I've updated my answer with an example that might give you an idea of how to do it.

Thank you, I appreciate the effort you went in going so in-depth. I have a better understanding of how something like this would work with SvelteKit now, and how the layouts need to be structured as data.

I feel like I should not answer my first question while am falling asleep but, using load functions in both +page.js and +layout.js to load data before rendering the routes should solve some of the problems, and
using a structure like src/routes/cms/[cmsId] to creates a route with a parameter that can be used to load data dynamically when a user requests a page like /cms/whateventheidmightbe should solve the rest of it.
Here you can take a look at Routing on the official docs
I hope this helps.

Thank you, I appreciate your help on this! It gives me good insight into the routing aspect.
